# Bose gas Hamiltonian in second quantization with indefinite parity potential

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, second-quantization, bose-einstein-condensate, bosons

In the book Bose-Einstein Condensation by Pitaevski, Lev; Petrovitch, and Sandro Stringari (Oxford University Press), the Hamiltonian for weakly interacting Bose gas reads as,
$$H=\sum\dfrac{p^2}{2m}\hat{a}_p^\dagger \hat{a}_p+\dfrac{1}{2V}\sum_{p_1,p_2,q} V_q \hat{a}_{p_1+q}^\dagger \hat{a}_{p_2-q}^\dagger \hat{a}_{p_1} \hat{a}_{p_2}\tag{1}\label{1}$$
In the book they have assumed $V_q=V_0$ to be independent of $q$. Expanding the second term one can write the following,
$$\dfrac{V_0}{2V} \hat{a}^\dagger_0 \hat{a}^\dagger_0 \hat{a}_0 \hat{a}_0+\dfrac{V_0}{2V}\sum_{q\neq0}(\hat{a}^\dagger_q\hat{a}_q+\hat{a}^\dagger_{-q}\hat{a}_{-q}+\hat{a}^\dagger_{q}\hat{a}^\dagger_{-q}+\hat{a}_{q}\hat{a}_{-q})\\
=\dfrac{V_0}{2V} \hat{a}^\dagger_0 \hat{a}^\dagger_0 \hat{a}_0 \hat{a}_0+\dfrac{V_0}{2V}\sum_{q\neq0}(2\hat{a}^\dagger_q\hat{a}_q+\hat{a}^\dagger_{q}\hat{a}^\dagger_{-q}+\hat{a}_{q}\hat{a}_{-q})
$$

However, in a thesis I saw $V_q$ was a function of $q$, although it was not specified what kind of function it was. In that case, the second term was expanded as follows,
$$\begin{eqnarray}
&&\dfrac{V_0}{2V} \hat{a}^\dagger_0 \hat{a}^\dagger_0 \hat{a}_0 \hat{a}_0+\dfrac{1}{2V}\sum_{q\neq0}[V_q(\hat{a}^\dagger_q\hat{a}_q+\hat{a}^\dagger_{-q}\hat{a}_{-q}+\hat{a}^\dagger_{q}\hat{a}^\dagger_{-q}+\hat{a}_{q}\hat{a}_{-q})]\tag{2}\label{2}\\  
&=&\dfrac{V_0}{2V} \hat{a}^\dagger_0 \hat{a}^\dagger_0 \hat{a}_0 \hat{a}_0+\dfrac{1}{2V}\sum_{q\neq0}[V_q(2\hat{a}^\dagger_q\hat{a}_q+\hat{a}^\dagger_{q}\hat{a}^\dagger_{-q}+\hat{a}_{q}\hat{a}_{-q})]\tag{3}\label{3}
\end{eqnarray}
$$
My question: Is it valid to go from \eqref{2} to \eqref{3} even when $V_q$ may be of indefinite parity(neither purely even nor purely odd)?
In short, is the following true if the operators are bosonic?
$$\sum_{q\neq0}V_q(\hat{a}^\dagger_q\hat{a}_q+\hat{a}^\dagger_{-q}\hat{a}_{-q})=2\sum_{q\neq0}V_q\hat{a}^\dagger_q\hat{a}_q$$

Answer (score 2):

In the book "Bose-Einstein Condensation" (page 27) the author wrote that $V(\vec{r})$ is a two-body potential.

We can therefore assume that this potential only depends on the distance between particles $|\vec{r}|$ (I don't have in mind another possible kind of two-body potential). So we have $V(\vec{r})=V(-\vec{r})$. And for the Fourier transform (I do it in 1D for simplicity of notations) :

$\begin{align}V_{-q}&=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dxe^{+iqx}V(x)\\ &=\int\limits_{+\infty}^{-\infty}(-dx)e^{-iqx}V(-x) \\&= \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dxe^{-iqx}V(x) \\ &=V_{q} \end{align}$

where I did the change of variable $x\rightarrow -x$ in the second line